# drag & drop image WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Подскажите, в чем ошибка.
Хочу чтобы с помощью drag&drop вставляло картинку, но после перетаскивания получаю объект `Image` со свойством `Source` равным null

XAML

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <StackPanel CanVerticallyScroll="True">
            <Image Source="Resources/part1.jpg" Width="280" Height="121" Margin="0,10,0,10" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Image Source="Resources/part2.jpg" Width="280" Height="121" Margin="0,10,0,10" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Image Source="Resources/part3.jpg" Width="280" Height="121" Margin="0,10,0,10" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Image Source="Resources/part4.jpg" Width="280" Height="121" Margin="0,10,0,10" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Image Source="Resources/part5.jpg" Width="280" Height="121" Margin="0,10,0,10" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Image Source="Resources/part6.jpg" Width="280" Height="121" Margin="0,10,0,10" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
        <Image Source="Resources/part1.jpg" Width="280" Height="120" Drop="Image_Drop" DragEnter="Image_DragEnter" AllowDrop="True" Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Left="156" Canvas.Top="51"/>
        <Image Source="Resources/part2.jpg" Width="280" Height="120" Drop="Image_Drop" AllowDrop="True" Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Left="436" Canvas.Top="51"/>
        <Image Source="Resources/part3.jpg" Width="280" Height="120" Drop="Image_Drop" AllowDrop="True" Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Left="156" Canvas.Top="170"/>
        <Image Source="Resources/part4.jpg" Width="280" Height="120" Drop="Image_Drop" AllowDrop="True" Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Left="436" Canvas.Top="170"/>
        <Image Source="Resources/part5.jpg" Width="280" Height="120" Drop="Image_Drop" AllowDrop="True" Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Left="156" Canvas.Top="288"/>
        <Image Source="Resources/part6.jpg" Width="280" Height="120" Drop="Image_Drop" AllowDrop="True" Stretch="UniformToFill" Canvas.Left="436" Canvas.Top="288"/>
    </Canvas>

</Grid>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Image_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Image) sender).Source = e.Source as ImageSource;
    }

    private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // sender – объект, на котором произошло данное событие.
        Image lbl = sender as Image;
        // Создаем источник.
        // Копируем содержимое метки Drop.
        // 1 параметр: Элемент управления, который будет источником.
        // 2 параметр: Данные, которые будут перемещаться.
        // 3 параметр: Эффект при переносе.
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbl, lbl.Source, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

    private void Image_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
}
```

ссылка на гит https://github.com/Sechik/Puzzle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У тебя Source разные(ты их пытаешся присвоить):

```
{pack://application:,,,/Puzzle;component/Resources/part3.jpg}
{System.Windows.Controls.Image}
```

Так происходит копирование, но картинка одна и та же в `sender` и `e`

```
private void Image_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        //((Image) sender).Source = e.Source as ImageSource;

        Image image = e.Source as Image;

        ((Image)sender).Source = image.Source;
    }
```

Вот готовое решение (здесь картинка передаётся через дополнительную переменную):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Puzzle
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static Image global_sender;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Image_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            //((Image) sender).Source = e.Source as ImageSource;

            //Image image = e.Source as Image;

            //((Image)sender).Source = image.Source;

            ((Image)sender).Source = global_sender.Source;
        }

        private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // sender – объект, на котором произошло данное событие.
            Image lbl = sender as Image;
            global_sender = lbl;
            // Создаем источник.
            // Копируем содержимое метки Drop.
            // 1 параметр: Элемент управления, который будет источником.
            // 2 параметр: Данные, которые будут перемещаться.
            // 3 параметр: Эффект при переносе.
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbl, lbl.Source, DragDropEffects.Copy);

        }

        private void Image_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Вот только есть еще пару вопросов:
1) что значит Source разные?
2)

        Image image = e.Source as Image;

            ((Image)sender).Source = image.Source;
зачем этот код?

Comment: В режиме отладки F5 поставь точку остановки на эти строчки, наведи курсор и раскрой всплывающее меню - там будет их содержимое.

Comment: Лишний код. убери